# arduino -lcd screen has weird noise with multiple pictures

Tags: arduino

I'm connecting an arduino to a [lcd screen](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php?title=SPI_LCD_Module_%28SKU:DFR0091%29) using the following [library](http://www.dfrobot.com/image/data/DFR0091/LCD12864RSPI%20v1.0.zip). For the display code I have written a simple piece of code that should display 2 picture os eyes (1 angry one friendly) and switching at regular intervals, however the display keeps showing me weird pixels around the borders that shouldn't be there, by making it show the same eyes twice this can be fixed however as long as I have both eyes being used it runs into trouble. Here is my code:

```
    void setup()
    {
      LCDA.initDriverPin(2,7,10); 
      LCDA.Initialise(); // INIT SCREEN  
      delay(100);
    }
    void loop(){
      LCDA.CLEAR(); //empty screen 
      delay(100);//wait for command to finish 

      LCDA.DrawFullScreen(eyes);
      delay(5000); //wait 5 seconds with eyes on the screen 

      LCDA.CLEAR();//clear screen
      delay(100);//wait for command to finish 
      LCDA.DrawFullScreen(angry); //show me the angry face 
      delay(5000);//wait 5 seconds with angry face on screen 
    }

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; DFrobot bitmap - size 128x64 pixels, black/white image
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 
unsigned char eyes[]={
0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xFE ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xFE ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xFE ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xFE ,0x7E ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xC6 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xF8 ,0x3E ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0x80 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xF0 ,0x1E ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0x80 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xC0 ,0x1E ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0x80 ,0x1E ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0x80 ,0xFE ,0xC2 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x7E ,0xF0 ,0x1E ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xF2 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0xFE ,0xF8 ,0x1E ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0x02 ,0xFE ,0xFA ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0xFE ,0xF8 ,0x1E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0x06 ,0xF2 ,0xFE ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0xFA ,0xFC ,0xFC ,0x1E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0x0E ,0xC0 ,0xFE ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xC0 ,0x7E ,0x0E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0x0E ,0x80 ,0x7E ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xC0 ,0x3E ,0x0E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0x1E ,0xFE ,0x3E ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x8E ,0xFE ,0x0E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x1E ,0xEE ,0x9E ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xBE ,0xFE ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x1E ,0x82 ,0xDE ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xBC ,0x6E ,0x86 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x3E ,0x82 ,0xDE ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xB8 ,0x2E ,0xC6 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x3E ,0x80 ,0xDE ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xB0 ,0x2E ,0xC6 ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x3C ,0x3E ,0x5E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x9E ,0x8E ,0xC2 ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x3C ,0x7E ,0x9E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xBE ,0xD6 ,0xC2 ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x7C ,0x7E ,0xDE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xBE ,0xC6 ,0xE2 ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x7C ,0xFE ,0xDE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xF6 ,0xE2 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x7A ,0xFE ,0xDE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xF6 ,0xE2 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x7A ,0xFE ,0xDE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xF2 ,0xE0 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x7A ,0xFE ,0xDE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xF2 ,0xE0 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x7A ,0xFE ,0xDE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xF2 ,0xE0 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x7A ,0xFE ,0xDE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xF2 ,0xE0 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x7A ,0xFE ,0xDE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xF2 ,0xE0 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xF0 ,0x7A ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFA ,0xE0 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xF0 ,0x7A ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFA ,0xE0 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xF0 ,0x7A ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFA ,0xE0 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xE0 ,0x7A ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFA ,0xE0 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xE0 ,0x7E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFA ,0xE0 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFC ,0x7E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xC0 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFE ,0x3E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xCE ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
};
unsigned char angry[]={
0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x30 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x7C ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x7E ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0x80 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x7E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0x80 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFE ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFC ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xF6 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xF0 ,0x7E ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xE0 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x1E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0x80 ,0x7E ,0x80 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xC0 ,0x1E ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xC0 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xE0 ,0x1E ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0xE0 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xF0 ,0x0C ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xF2 ,0x00 ,0xE6 ,0xE0 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x7E ,0x30 ,0x04 ,0x3E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xC2 ,0x8E ,0xE2 ,0xF0 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x7C ,0x30 ,0x0C ,0x0E ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x9E ,0x82 ,0xF0 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x3E ,0x1C ,0x06 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFE ,0x02 ,0x98 ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x3E ,0x18 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xF8 ,0x02 ,0x18 ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x06 ,0x18 ,0x02 ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xE0 ,0x06 ,0x18 ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x02 ,0x18 ,0xFE ,0x1E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0xC0 ,0x06 ,0x78 ,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x02 ,0x18 ,0xFE ,0x0E ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x66 ,0x8C ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x7C ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x02 ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x02 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFC ,0x7E ,0xC6 ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x7C ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xFC ,0x38 ,0xE6 ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x7C ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0xE0 ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xC0 ,0x3E ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x76 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x7C ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0xFA ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xF0 ,0xFE ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xF6 ,0x80 ,0x7C ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0xBA ,0xFE ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0xF6 ,0xF0 ,0xFE ,0x78 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x3C ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x8E ,0xFE ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0xF0 ,0xF8 ,0x7C ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xFC ,0xF8 ,0xFC ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x86 ,0xFE ,0x98 ,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x60 ,0x60 ,0x7C ,0x70 ,0x1E ,0xF8 ,0x3E ,0xFC ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x82 ,0xFE ,0x9C ,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7C ,0x7C ,0xFE ,0xF8 ,0x06 ,0x7C ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0xFE ,0x8E ,0xE0 ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7C ,0x6E ,0xFE ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x7C ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x06 ,0xF0 ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7C ,0x76 ,0x9E ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x7C ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x3A ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0x30 ,0x0E ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x02 ,0x82 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xF0 ,0x06 ,0xEC ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x06 ,0x02 ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xE0 ,0x06 ,0x0C ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0xFC ,0x06 ,0x02 ,0x80 ,0x06 ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xC0 ,0x02 ,0x0C ,0x00 ,0xF8 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x7E ,0x06 ,0x00 ,0x80 ,0x0E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0x80 ,0x06 ,0x0C ,0x02 ,0xF0 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x7E ,0x06 ,0x00 ,0x80 ,0x1E ,0xC0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x1E ,0x80 ,0x0E ,0x0C ,0x02 ,0xF0 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x3E ,0x3E ,0x00 ,0xC0 ,0x1E ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xC0 ,0x1C ,0x0C ,0x06 ,0xE0 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xBC ,0x00 ,0xC0 ,0x3E ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x38 ,0x0C ,0x0E ,0xE0 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x1E ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0xC0 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xF0 ,0x70 ,0x0E ,0x1E ,0xC0 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0xC0 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFC ,0x60 ,0x06 ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x06 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0xF6 ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x60 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x06 ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFA ,0xFE ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xF8 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x3E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0xE0 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0E ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x02 ,0xFE ,0xFE ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0xFE ,0xF0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x7E ,0xFC ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 
};
```

each time I re upload the image it changes the way the noise patterns look suggesting this is some kind of overflow problem. However changing the last byte of the bitmaps creates lines at the bottom of the screen, right where the noise is on one of the images. Note that with different images this noise can very much "cut" into the images even creating not active pixels (0's) rather then just set ones. Suggesting that the images themselves to at least fit the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because these pictures were saved in SRAM rather then in flash memory they took up so much space that the arduino ran out of memory causing various types of noise to appear(along side a few other problems such as random crashes/reboots). By moving them out of SRAM and into flash memory the problem was solved.